# Prove that a two digit number is divisible by the sum of its digits if it is divisible by $9$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that a two-digit number with non-zero digits (except $99$) is divisible by the sum of its digits if the number is divisible by $9$.

Comment: The condition does not satisfy for $99$.

Comment: Yes, I meant except 99.

Comment: Aside from abstract means (not at all difficult), there aren't very many cases to check.

Comment: There are only $9$ cases.

Comment: I know, I actually encountered this problem while doing a similar question:Prove that a three-digit number (except 999.) is divisible by the sum of its digits if the number is divisible by 18. So, I guess the proof would be similar for both

Comment: You mean 10 is divisible by 1so it must be divisible by 9

Comment: The three digit case is (slightly) less trivial.  For any $n$, the sum of the digits of $n$ is congruent to $n\pmod 9$.  Thus, knowing that $n$ is divisible by $18$ tells us that the sum of the digits of $n$ is divisible by $9$...thus it is $\in \{9,18,27\}$. You rule out $27$ when you exclude $999$ so....

Comment: To close voter: The question is quite clear, and there is nothing in this question which is missing. And for god's sake, please don't think that I m saying this  because I have answered this question, I have already got 200 today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to prove that if a number is divisible by $9$ then sum of its digits will also be divisible by $9$, you can do it that way:

Suppose the two digit number about which we are talking is of the form $10a+b$. As given $9|10a+b\implies 9|10a+b+9b\implies9|10(a+b)\implies9|a+b$.

It is clear that Sum of two digits can never be greater than $18$ (maximum being $9+9$ in case of $99$). So either sum of digits is $9$ or $18$, $18$ in the case of $99$ which is the only exception. And for all other pairs of digits $(a,b)$ the sum of digits $(a+b)$ is going to be $9$.

As $9|10a+b \implies 9=a+b|10a+b$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let the two-digit number be $10a+b$ for $a,b \in [0,9] \cap \Bbb{N}$. We know that $9 \mid (10a+b)$. We also know that $9 \mid 9a$, so we get:
$$9 \mid ((10a+b)-9a) \implies 9 \mid (a+b)$$
Now, since $a,b \in [0,9] \cap \Bbb{N}$, we have $0 \leq a+b \leq 18$. Now that we know $9 \mid (a+b)$, we know that $a+b \in \{0,9,18\}$.

Case 1: $a+b=0$: The only way this can happen is if $a=b=0$, meaning $10a+b=0$, which is not a two-digit number, so we don't need to prove this case.

Case 2: $a+b=9$: We have $9 \mid (10a+b) \implies (a+b) \mid (10a+b)$.

Case 3: $a+b=18$: This can only happen if $a=b=9$, which means $10a+b=99$. This is stated as an exception in the theorem, so we don't need to prove this case.

Thus, we have proven all of the cases we needed to prove for this theorem, so we are done.

Comment: I’m sorry, but zero is not a divisor any number except $0$: the definition is that $a|b$ if and only if there is $m$ with $am=b$. I think the point is that only your case $2$ occurs (once $99$ is excluded).

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for the catch! I've fixed my proof above.

Comment: Though long but good answer, +1

Answer (score 0):

$$(9)(1)=9$$

To get to $9(2)$ we add $9$ to $9(1)$, to get to $9k$ we add $9$ to $9(k-1)$. Or in other words we add $10-1$ subtracting $1$ from the units digit then adding $1$ to the tens digit. Subtracting $1$ then adding $1$ preserves the digit sum of $9$ because $x+1-1=x$, when assuming no carrying over complications happen. The only trouble we get to is when we run into a $0$ in the units place, then we have to do some carrying over. This occurs for the first time when we want to add $10-1$ to $9(10)$ (it's easy to check it does not occur at $9(5)$). However we are good before then, so it follows that the digit sum for $9(1),9(2),....9(10)$ are all $9$. And our numbers are all multiples of $9$, so they are divisible by their digit sum.